# Angular inputs not being empty on page load when using ng-model inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` to create a user form but I'm struggling a bit. When I bind the inputs to the scope with the names in the `signupForm.modelBindings` array the names are set as the `input` value, and obviously that's not what I want. How do I bind the inputs to the scope whilst leaving the inputs empty?

**P.S**: It feels like I'm trying to do this in a very nooby way, is there an even better way of achieving what I want without having to create a lot of arrays containing the values?

**EDIT:** I found a better solution but I still have the problem of the inputs not being empty. Take a look at updated code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in signupForm" 
    class="data-row">
    <td class="label-cell data-cell">
        <label ng-bind="(row.description) + ':'"></label>
    </td>
    <td class="data-cell">
        <input type="{{row.type}}" ng-model="row.model"
               placeholder="{{row.description}}" 
               class="round input">
    </td>
    <td class="error-cell data-cell">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The info for the form:

```
$scope.signupForm = [
    {
        description: 'Firstname',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'user.firstname'
    },
    {
        description: 'Lastname',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'user.lastname'
    },
    {
        description: 'Date of birth',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'user.dateOfBirth'
    },
    {
        description: 'Country',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'user.country'
    },
    {
        description: 'Display name',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'user.displayName'
    },
    {
        description: 'E-mail',
        type: 'email',
        model: 'user.email'
    },
    {
        description: 'Password',
        type: 'password',
        model: 'user.firstname'
    },
    {
        description: 'Confirm password',
        type: 'password',
        model: 'user.confirmPassword'
    }
]
```

I tried clearing it by setting the scopes to empty strings but it didn't work:

```
$scope.firstname, $scope.lastname, $scope.dateOfBirth, 
$scope.country, $scope.displayName, $scope.email, 
$scope.password, $scope.confirmedPassword = '';
```

Comment: what is ``getNumber(number)``?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe A function that returns an array of X number of indexes. So that I can loop that amount of times.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I've updated the code to another solution, should make more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have this object :

```
$scope.user = {
     firstName: '',
     lastName: '',
     ...
}
```

With an info for your form which would be like that :

```
$scope.signupForm = [
{
    description: 'Firstname',
    type: 'text',
    model: 'firstname'
},
{
    description: 'Lastname',
    type: 'text',
    model: 'lastname'
},
```

You should be able to access it that way :

```
ng-model="user[row.model]"
```

**EDIT (opinion based) :**

Depending on the case, this solution might be a good option. That way, you just have to send the object "user" to save it.

I would have done it with a little difference. I would have received this object from back-end :

```
[{
   description : "Firstname",
   type: "text",
   value: ""
 },
 {
   description:
   ...
```

and I would have had my ng-model that way :

```
 ng-model="row.value"
```

And because I'm a bit lazy, I would have sent back the description, type,... to the back end.

The second option may be easier if that kind of model is supposed to change sometimes.

Comment: That works, would you say this is the best way of going about creating a form using ng-repeat? Having an array of objects and accessing the proper info this way?